# In Rebol how to get the Parent in an Object Path?

Tags: rebol

Is there a function to get the parent of an object for example

```
parent-of system/console/history
```

would give

```
system/console
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't realise that a path! value is a type of series! value:

```
>> path: 'system/console/history   
== system/console/history
>> type? path                   
== path!
>> series? path                 
== true
```

So just remove the last value in the series:

```
>> path: head remove back tail path
== system/console
```

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right if the **history** object has just one parent. But it may have others:

```
my-block: copy []
append my-block system/console/history
```

my-object: make object! [history: system/console/history]

**history** is now has three legitimate parents:

1. system/console
2. my-block
3. my-object/history

Which you consider to the the real parent is really up to you. There is no easy way that I know of to find all the contexts an object (or block) is part of.